# Reinstalling macOS

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I currently have a Mac that only has Windows 10 installed. I would like to create a partition and reinstall macOS on that partition without erasing any of my Windows data. Does anyone know of a good way to do this? My default is to make a backup of my data, erase the disk, install macOS, and go through the whole Bootcamp process again, but I would rather avoid erasing anything if at all possible.

Comment: How is your drive currently partitioned? GPT with one big NTFS volume taking up the whole drive?

Comment: @Spiff Yep, GPT with one big NTFS volume (plus one partition for EFI)